# Can a rational function ( with linear num. & denom.) always be expressed as a composition of elementary ( invertible) functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, inverse-function, elementary-functions

I would like to apply the following rule in order to find the inverse function of a given function :

> if function $f(x)= h(i(j(x)))$ and if functions $h(x)$, $i(x)$ and
>   $j(x)$ are invertible, then $f^{-1}(x) = j^{-1}(i^{-1}(h^{-1}(x)))$.

In order to apply this rule to a rational function such as :

$ f(x) = \frac {6x+4} {4x+5}$ ( Source : Larson's College Algebra, Unit 2.7, exercise #53)

I would need to express function $f$ as a composition of elementary invertible functions.

Is this possible?

Hence my question: suppose a rational function $f$ is a quotient of two first degree polynomials, is it always possible to express $f$ as a composition of elementary ( invertible) functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of this as a Möbius Transformation. I'm sure this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation#Simple_M%C3%B6bius_transformations_and_composition
answers your question positively. It can always be done.